# В некоторых случаях поле advanced custom fields не выводится на странице сайта

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

Использую Wordpress+Masterstudy. Сайт с онлайн курсами. Курсы размещаются в категориях (в плагине это кастомная таксономия). Задумал отображать в категориях курсов также новости, отобранные по тегам, установил для этой цели плагин Advanced Custom Fields

Создал группу полей для таксономии course category, создали поле wysiwyg editor.

В админке поле в course category выводится и настраивается корректно.

В поля добавляю новости по определенным тегам через шорткоды

В шаблон вывода course category добавил:

`<?php the_field('coursenewsbytags'); ?>`

В случаях где категория курсов пустая, как например [здесь](https://u-intosai.org/course-category/idi/) поле выводится корректно и материалы новостей под категорией курса отображаются. В категории отображается No courses found, а ниже идут новости, все верно.

Но там где в категории имеются курсы поле с новостями [не выводится](https://u-intosai.org/course-category/cbc/) .

Понимаю, что есть какой-то конфликт с отображением списка курсов плагина masterstudy и плагином advanced custom fields, но не могу понять как это устранить.

```
    <?php if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit; //Exit if accessed directly ?>

<?php $term = get_queried_object();
stm_lms_register_style('taxonomy_archive');

$args = array(
    'per_row' => STM_LMS_Options::get_option('courses_per_row', 4),
    'posts_per_page' => STM_LMS_Options::get_option('courses_per_page', get_option('posts_per_page')),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'stm_lms_course_taxonomy',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $term->term_id,
        )
    ),
    'class' => 'archive_grid'
);

?>

<h2><?php echo sanitize_text_field($term->name); ?></h2>


<?php if (!empty($term->description)): ?>
    <p>
        <?php echo wp_kses_post($term->description); ?>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="stm_lms_courses">
    <?php STM_LMS_Templates::show_lms_template('courses/grid',
        array(
            'args' => $args
        )
    ); ?>

    <?php STM_LMS_Templates::show_lms_template('courses/load_more',
        array(
            'args' => $args
        )
    ); ?>

</div>

<?php the_field('coursenewsbytags'); ?>
```

Comment: Для вывода в шаблоне таксономии или из конкретной таксономии, нужно прокидывать `$taxonomy . '_' . $term_id`, `'term_' . $term_id` или объект `WP_Term` в `the_field()` вторым параметром, подробнее можете почитать [здесь](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/#notes)

Comment: @Simon комментарий правильный и заслуживает быть оформленным как ответ.

Comment: @Simon А почему тогда в данном случае все работает на этой странице https://u-intosai.org/course-category/idi/ ? Я пробовал подставлять не только wysiwyg, но и другие поля, там такая же история

Comment: @VictorGorbunov мне тяжело судить что там у Вас работает, лично я там ничего не вижу `No courses found.`. Возможно здесь присутствует еще какая-то проблема, но все что Вы предоставили это кусочек кода `<?php the_field('coursenewsbytags'); ?>` и больше ничего, так очень тяжело сделать какой-то вывод о Вашей проблеме. Основываясь на этом, я Вам указал на очевидную ошибку в том коде, который Вы привели.

Comment: @Simon Спасибо за ваш комментарий. Но возможно вы меня неправильно поняли. No courses found - здесь как раз все в порядке, так и должно быть, там материалы новостей отображаются, я полагаю так как нет списка курсов и поэтому нет конфликта. Мне нужно чтобы такой список отображался и в тех категориях где есть курсы. Я обновил описание тикета, добавил полный код файла

Comment: Попробовал решение из первого комментария, не работает